# Increase canvas size on a drawing in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drawings

I am using the drawing tool in google sheets to create a flowchart. My flowchart requires more space than the standard canvas size. How can increase the canvas size?

I could not find an option to adjust the ruler. I also could not find an option to add the shapes for the flowchart direction on the sheet, I had to go through the drawing tool.

Comment: if the drawing is saved in to the Sheet via `Insert > Drawing`, isn't it possible just to select it and modify its size by dragging a hot corner pulling it down the sheet?

Comment: Yes it is, but I need to add more components to my drawing before I get to that stage. I found out that it is not possible to do what I want to do. I just have to make things smaller and make them fit on the space provided, when when the drawing is saved in the sheet I can then grab a hot corner and pull to expand.